# Recognize click from MotionEvent stream

Tags: android, touch, touch-event

Is there a way to detect a click from `MotionEvent`s in Android? To be more specific, I need a way to distinct two kind of events: movement and click (I'm more interested in the latter).

For example, this kind of behavior can be observed in `MapView` component: if you drag the map just a little - it does not move (I would call this a click), however if movement distance is bigger the map starts to move as well (I would call this movement). Is there a standard threshold (global parameter) or other method to distinct these two actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement an [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html). `onSingleTapUp()` will be called for a click type event and `onScroll()` will be called for a movement type event.